# Exibir outro resultado antes do input

Tags: python, input

Estou criando um código para analisar as atividades enviadas pelos alunos de uma escola.
A ideia é fazer cada atividade aparecer, uma a uma no meu notebook e através de um input eu disparar outros códigos, de acordo com a ação pretendida para a atividade analisada.

Acontece que, quando visualizado na mesma célula, ou eu consigo visualizar o PDF ou o input.

Minha intenção era conseguir visualizar ambas as coisas, pois a resposta para o input depende da informação descrita no pdf.

Aqui é um exemplo do que ocorre quando ainda não inseri o input. A janela com o PDF é exibida normalmente:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

---

Já aqui, um exemplo do que ocorre quando eu insiro o input. O jupyter ignora a exibição do PDF e pula para a caixa de texto:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma forma de eu exibir os dois elementos na mesma célula?

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que a sua função PDF seja como [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470099/view-pdf-image-in-an-ipython-notebook), então seria possível juntar o HTML inicial de abertura de PDF com um input HTML. Por exemplo:

```
class PDF(object):
    def __init__(self, pdf, size=(200,200)):
        self.pdf = pdf
        self.size = size

    def _repr_html_(self):
        return f"<iframe src={self.pdf} width={self.size[0]} height={self.size[1]}></iframe>"+'''<br/>
            Selecione uma opção abaixo:<br/>
            1 - Devolver para estudante.<br/>
            2 - Encaminhar para Coordenador.<br/>
            3 - Indeferir.<br/>
            <input type="text" 
            onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                alert(this.value)
            }">
        '''

    def _repr_latex_(self):
        return r'\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{{{0}}}'.format(self.pdf)

a = PDF('hat.pdf',size=(800,200))
```

Assim, quando `a` for chamado em outro bloco ele não só retornará o PDF, como também retornará um input de texto. Dentro do input, quando a tecla `Enter` (código 13) é pressionada, coloquei a função de `alert` do JavaScript (JS) que poderia ser substituída pela função desejada, caso fosse solucionável em JS.

Caso a função devesse retornar algum valor ao Python, eu sei que o comando seria algo como `IPython.notebook.kernel.execute("motivo="+this.value)`, mas não consegui fazer funcionar nesse contexto.